# TOR relay arm command not found - raspberry

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, tor

I followed [this procedure from GitHub](https://github.com/mricon/tor-relay-bootstrap-rpi) to set up a tor relay on a raspberry pi under Raspbian Buster. When I want to check if my TOR relay is running, I send the `sudo -u debian-tor arm` command, however, the answer I have is `sudo: arm: command not found`.

Any idea what the issue could be ? thanks !

Comment: I am having the same problem. Anyone found a solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

The tool was renamed to `nyx`

See: https://nyx.torproject.org/

So just run `sudo -u debian-tor nyx` and it will work.